# Executing multiple SQL queries with Python Flask

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python function which should execute 2 SQL queries. I have found that it is impossible to execute 2 queries in one command at once, so as a workaround I created a list of my queries and try to iterate over it with execute command. However nothing is added to MySQL table. Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/addComment', methods=['POST'])
def addComment():
    try:
        if session.get('user'):
            _description = request.form['description']
            _user = session.get('user')
            _term_id = request.form['termID']
            _time = datetime.now()
            operation = ['"INSERT INTO comments (description, user, termID, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (_description, _user, _term_id, _time)', '"INSERT INTO history (user, term, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (_user, _term_id, _time)']

            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            for item in operation:
                cursor.execute()
                conn.commit()
                data = cursor.fetchall()
            

            if len(data) == 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'status':'OK'})
            else:
                return json.dumps({'status':'ERROR'})
    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'status':'Unauthorized access'})
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: You are not passing the item to cursor.execute. Also fetchall() will not returning anything, so you will need to commit anyway

Comment: Thanks! Corrected 'cursor.execute(item)'. Would you please clarify how can I fix issue with fetchall()? What should I correct to return the function result?

Comment: What value do you want to get from fetachall()?

Comment: I used it to validate the result and return the status: if len(data) == 0: etc. Now I removed this fragment, but the function still doesn't work - nothing added to the table

Answer (score 1):

Errors in your code lies in the following areas:

**A. On iteration sql statement is not passed to `execute()`**

Should be:

```python
for item in operation:
    cursor.execute(item)
    conn.commit()
```

B. **Invalid parameterization**

```python
'"INSERT INTO comments (description, user, termID, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (_description, _user, _term_id, _time)'
```

This string statement doesn't apply variables to SQL statement string. Depending on your value types you should decide whether to add `'` (apostrophe) or not. More safely would be to pass parameters to `.execute()` function. Example below.

```python
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO comments (description, user, termID, time) VALUES (:description, :user, :term_id, :time)",
    description=_description,
    user=_user,
    term_id=_term_id,
    time=_time
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I have corrected both points, but it still doesn't work. It worked with one SQL query (without for cycle, with single cursore.execute() command) with initial parameterinzation. So I guess there is something wrong with cursore.execute() command inside the cycle, but I can't figure it out

Comment: Just for test I inserted the SQL query directly to cursor.execute: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO comments (description, user, termID, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (_description, _user, _term_id, _time))` inside the loop. It works! So it seems that 'item' is not recorgnized as cursor.execute() argument